# Choosing the right power cord for my PC adapter

Tags: voltage, power, fuses, pc

I need to replace the euro power cord on my new PC with a UK one.

The power adapter for the PC has the following rating:

Input: AC100-240V - 50-60Hz, 3.5A
Output: 19.5V (direct current) 11.8A

The original (european) power cord plug is 250V with a 16A fuse.

Looking online I can not find a UK power cord with a 16A fuse, best I can find is a 13A fuse 250V power cord.

I'm assuming the 13A fuse is enough, but would I get away with a 10A fuse too? The input for power adapter is 3.5A as mentioned above but output is 11.8A so I'm a little lost here.

Comment: Yes, it's the input current that matters here since this is the input side of the adapter.

Comment: European power cords (most likely you mean Schuko) do not have fuses like UK plugs do. However the plugs and cables may have a max rated current printed on them.

Comment: NB: This advice is "common sense" based and not utterly 'by the book'. ie a purist would probably say to fit a slow-blow 2A fuse - see below) || This is very non critical - as long as the cord current rating meets or exceeds the adapter **INPUT** current rating it is liable to be acceptable. Ideally fusing should be suited to the maximum load current (which may be only 1.75A as the 3.5A rating will apply at 100 VAC). BUT if the adapter is a quality product it is exceedingly unlikely that it will fail in a manner which causes the primary fuse to blow. ...

Comment: ...  And, should this happen, typical faults will blow a fuse of almost any sensible size.

Answer (score 3):

The input of 3.5A will only be taken with the lowest input voltage. At 240v, you will be drawing less than 2A.

Ideally, you'll fuse your mains input at 3A, which although it's a common standard, it can be difficult to find other than 13A fused UK power cords. If you have to buy a 13A cord, then also buy some 3A fuses, and change the fuse.

Answer (score 1):

Conventionally you'll find a 13A or 3A fuse inside of a UK plug. 10A fuse is fine if your cable flex CSA is 1mm2 or greater thickness. 5A sounds like the sensible option, 3A may blow but perhaps unlikely.

Remember your mains cable connector fuse is primarily there to protect the cable flex from overheating rather than the target device.